# Struct variable not updated

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js

I have a simple contract that takes integer inputs from different clients and eventually calls a function to calculate average. When I run the contract in Remix debugger, I can see the function go through correctly. But, I can't seem to get the same from `web3.js`. Can you please suggest what am I missing?

The [Solidity documentation on storage](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-is-the-memory-keyword-what-does-it-do) is so poorly worded that, I can't follow it at all!

> The types where the so-called storage location is important are
>   structs and arrays. If you e.g. pass such variables in function calls,
>   their data is not copied if it can stay in memory or stay in storage.
>   This means that you can modify their content in the called function
>   and these modifications will still be visible in the caller.

This is with Ethereum Testrpc.

**Contract**

*Setting `runningNumber` and `members[]` is not shown here.*

```
contract Lister {
    struct ListMembers {
        bytes32[] members;
        uint256 averageNumber; 
        uint256 runningNumber;  
    }

    // Instance of the ListMemebers struct
    ListMembers public lm;

   function calculateAverageNumber() {        
        uint256 numMembers = uint256(lm.members.length);
        uint256 sampleSum = lm.runningNumber - lm.randomNumber;
        uint256 avgSum = sampleSum / numMembers;
        lm.averageNumber = avgSum;
    }

     function getAverageNumber() returns (uint256) {
        return lm.averageNumber;
    }
```

**web3.js**

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var fs = require('fs');
//
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
var abiFile = fs.readFileSync('Lister.abi').toString();
var abiDef = JSON.parse(abiFile);
var ListingContract = web3.eth.contract(abiDef);
var contractInstance = ListingContract.at('0xdc80....3aff');
//
contractInstance.getAverageNumber.call(
    (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(res)
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: can you add the code for the initial setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mark `getAverageNumber()` `constant`. Otherwise you won't be able to read it from `web3.js`. See this answer for more about what this means: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867572/solidity-return-function-why-the-constant

Comment: That didn't work. I have another function `getRunningNumber` that returns `lm.runningNumber` correctly without the `constant` modifier. How can I confirm that `lm.averageNumber` is actually getting updated?